# How to calculate the energy of a slingshot projectile?

Tags: hunting, slingshots

This [answer](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/19661/8794) made me wonder how a slingshot would compare in power to an airgun, especially as for that location, without a license you are limited to [12 ft-lbs of energy](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/15912/8794). For hunting with firearms, more energy means that you are more likely to get a clean kill, and a minimum level is often mandated by law in the United States for hunting a species.

I looked for data, but there really isn't much especially as compared to airguns and it probably depends on the person.

How would one **calculate the energy of a slingshot projectile**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, you need the weight of the projectile and its velocity. The way to measure the velocity is to use a [modern gun chronograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun_chronograph#Modern_chronograph), you shoot the projectile through the to screens and it will measure the velocity for you.

Then you take the weight of the projectile and plug it into the equation,

```
(weight in grains * velocity in feet per second squared)/450240
```

[Equation Source](https://www.pyramydair.com/article/What_is_Muzzle_Energy_August_2003/5)

or you could plug the numbers into an online calculator like any of these

- [Airgun Calculators](https://www.airgundepot.com/airgun-calculators-article.html)
- [Foot lbs of energy](https://www.beartoothbullets.com/rescources/calculators/php/energy.htm)
- [Bullet kinetic energy calculator](http://www.shooterscalculator.com/bullet-kinetic-energy.php)

and get the result.

Ft-lbs of energy aren't everything when it comes to getting clean kills but as a comparison between one projectile and another, it's probably the easiest to do.